# Unable to use native iOS component in react-native WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, webview

I have a native swift component `PhoneWebView` I use this to display click to call phone links web views by inheriting it in my JS file. Although I am using `if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){` in my previous file call to display different content for iOS and Android still I am getting the below error not sure what's missing. Could someone please correct me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTQtS.png

```
ERROR    Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name ATMWebView

This error is located at:
    in FileRenderWebView (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneVie
```

```
    import React, {   } from 'react';
    import {requireNativeComponent, SafeAreaView, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
    import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
    
    export default function FileRenderWebView({route, navigation}) {    
        const PhoneWebView = requireNativeComponent('ATMWebView');    
        useFocusEffect(
          React.useCallback(() => {            
            console.log("filerenderwebview----****");    
          }, [route.params]))
    
        return (
         <>
                     <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
                     <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
                       <PhoneWebView
                         uri="https://www.apple.com/contact/"
                         style={{flex: 1}}
                         onLoaded={pageLoaded}
                       />
                     </SafeAreaView>                   
         </>
        )
    }
```

Comment: this only occurs on fast refresh/ hot reloading, does it?

Comment: It occurs on both of refresh and hot reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you import directly native UI component, it will be reloaded when you use hot reloading or fast refresh.

my solution:

split `requireNativeComponent` to another file (in case i call `ATMWebViewComponent.js`) like this:

```
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

const ATMWebView = requireNativeComponent('ATMWebView');

export default ATMWebView;
```

then in the place you just need to import it and use:

`import ATMWebView from 'path_to_ ATMWebViewComponent.js_file'`

Comment: That did the trick and worked. Thanks so much!